# how to do update on dubplicate in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

My table has a primary key. while inserting the data, the key may or may not exist.
I want to insert data into the table. During insert if the key is already found, it needs to do an update instead. How do i do it a single update?

Note: This is for sybase database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sybase makes at least four different database products (Adaptive Server Enterprise, SQL Anywhere, Sybase IQ, and Advantage Database Server), so you should be specific as to which one and which version.

If you are using Sybase SQL Anywhere or Sybase IQ, you can use the `ON EXISTING UPDATE` clause of the [insert statement](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/insert-statement.html).

*Disclaimer: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: @Graeme Perrow any suggestions when using ASE/15.5? I'm noticing ON EXISTING UPDATE does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I worked on SQL Anywhere - I know very little about ASE.